# How to create a SOAP message in c#?

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2012, soap

I am Looking for a creating a soap Message in c#,
here i have created a client using the command from command prompt now trying to create a soap Message,but I am very new to this concept so unable to find the correct way so does any one have Idea regarding this?

Comment: What command did you run to create client? Can you share the client code to? What code you have written for creating SOAP message?

Comment: What you are passing, where you are passing, why you are passing, what mistake you are making, we can't know without seeing your code. So if you need us to provide best fitting solution of your problem please share the code.

Answer (score 3):

Sample code to create soap request

```
using System;  
using System.IO;  
using System.Net;  
using System.Xml;  

namespace UsingSOAPRequest  
{  
    public class Program  
    {  
        static void Main(string[] args)  
        {  
            //creating object of program class to access methods  
            Program obj = new Program();  
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Input values..");  
            //Reading input values from console  
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());  
            int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());  
            //Calling InvokeService method  
            obj.InvokeService(a, b);  
        }  
        public void InvokeService(int a, int b)  
        {  
            //Calling CreateSOAPWebRequest method  
            HttpWebRequest request = CreateSOAPWebRequest();  

            XmlDocument SOAPReqBody = new XmlDocument();  
            //SOAP Body Request  
            SOAPReqBody.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>  
            <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-   instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">  
             <soap:Body>  
                <Addition xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">  
                  <a>" + a + @"</a>  
                  <b>" + b + @"</b>  
                </Addition>  
              </soap:Body>  
            </soap:Envelope>");  


            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())  
            {  
                SOAPReqBody.Save(stream);  
            }  
            //Geting response from request  
            using (WebResponse Serviceres = request.GetResponse())  
            {  
                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(Serviceres.GetResponseStream()))  
                {  
                    //reading stream  
                    var ServiceResult = rd.ReadToEnd();  
                    //writting stream result on console  
                    Console.WriteLine(ServiceResult);  
                    Console.ReadLine();  
                }  
            }  
        }  

        public HttpWebRequest CreateSOAPWebRequest()  
        {  
            //Making Web Request  
            HttpWebRequest Req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://localhost/Employee.asmx");  
            //SOAPAction  
            Req.Headers.Add(@"SOAPAction:http://tempuri.org/Addition");  
            //Content_type  
            Req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";  
            Req.Accept = "text/xml";  
            //HTTP method  
            Req.Method = "POST";  
            //return HttpWebRequest  
            return Req;  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: do i need to add anything in .config file?